Does MLE on more samples always have a lower risk?
Denote the MLE on $n$ i.i.d. samples with $\hat{\theta}_{n} = \arg\max_\theta \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i; \theta)$. I wonder if adding more samples always makes the risk lower, or at least not higher. In particular, let $\theta^\ast$ be the true parameter, $\|\cdot\|_2$ and $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ be the $\ell^2$ and $\ell^\infty$ norm respectively. Is any of the following statement true? Feel free to impose some regularity conditions.
$$
\mathbb{E}\|\hat{\theta}_{n+1} - \theta^\ast\|_2 \le \mathbb{E}\|\hat{\theta}_{n} - \theta^\ast\|_2 \\
\mathbb{E}\|\hat{\theta}_{n+1} - \theta^\ast\|_\infty \le \mathbb{E}\|\hat{\theta}_{n} - \theta^\ast\|_\infty
$$
Note that I am asking about the risk (i.e. expected error); the error $\|\hat{\theta}_{n+1} - \theta^\ast\|$ does not have to smaller than $\|\hat{\theta}_{n} - \theta^\ast\|$ almost surely (see this question for that).
In fact, the exact model family I care about is logistic regression, but I think a more general result for MLE should exist.

I don't think the title question matches the equations. You can of course draw "unlucky" samples that pull your parameter estimate further away from the true value, there's no reason every additional observation must improve the parameter estimate. But the equations seem to ask if adding samples is always expected to improve the MLE, not if adding samples always improves the MLE.

@NuclearHoagie I'm asking about the expectation. The question has been updated to reflect that!

Except for special families, such as the Gaussian for $L^2$ minimization, MLE has nothing to do with risk.  You should therefore be looking for counterexamples to your proposition.  Note, too, that these expectations do not necessarily even exist or be finite.  Consider, too, that these norms can change dramatically when $\theta$ is reparameterized without changing the MLE at all.
